# 2nd Variable in url in echoing

Tags: php, cookies, get, echo, urlvariables

Ok, I am trying to get a variable from a url using PHP. Currently the site I am working with gets a the first url and sets it as a cookie. I am trying to get the second url and use it with our analytics software. The current url is:
http://www.peeweepenguin.com?cu=10031 the url I am trying to use is http://www.peeweepenguin.com?cu=10031&MyID=SomeCompany

When putting the link like this http://www.peeweepenguin.com?MyID=SomeCompany I can get the url to echo out. However I cannot get it to work when echoing it out with the url above (http://www.peeweepenguin.com?cu=10031&MyID=SomeCompany)

Here is the code I am working with:

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_GET['MyID']));
    $currentCUSite = $_GET['MyID'];
    ?>
```

Code above is in head tag.

```
    <?php echo $currentCUSite; ?>
```

Code above is located in body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement isn't working properly.

```
if (isset($_GET['MyID']));
                         ^
```

That semicolon terminates your `if` statement and the statement below it will get executed every time.

Change your code to:

```
if (isset($_GET['MyID'])) {
    $currentCUSite = $_GET['MyID'];
}
```

Or:

```
$currentCUSite = (isset($_GET['MyID'])) ? $currentCUSite : '';
```

And in your body, you can do:

```
<?php if(isset($currentCUSite)) echo $currentCUSite; ?>
```